# Base word for same word is different using spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-processing, lemmatization

I am trying to extract base word for an entire text however it reacts differently for a same word coming at different locations. Below is the code for reference:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import spacy
import pandas as pd

ps = PorterStemmer()

# spacy.cli.download("en")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

words = [  "meeting","eating", "adjustable",  "meeting", "eats", "eating", "eat", "ate", "rafting", "better", "good", "best", 'coming', "ability", "steal", "stolen", 'children']
word_joined = " ".join(words)
# print(word_joined)
doc = nlp(word_joined)

words_lemma = []
words_stemm = []


words_stemm = [ps.stem(w) for w in words]
words_lemma = [w.lemma_ for w in doc]

pd.DataFrame(list(zip(words, words_stemm, words_lemma)))
```

[image]

Is it something related to positioning of the word in a sentence from linguistical prospective?

Comment: Maybe it's the [dependency tree](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-shortest-dependency-path-with-spacy-and-stanfordnlp-539d45d28239)? But this seems to be a [common occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118213/spacy-lemmatizing-inconsistency-with-lemma-lookup-table)

Comment: Your not using the `nlp()` correctly. This is intended to work on full sentences or documents, not random words. The issue is that the `parser` is assigning different part-of-speech (POS) tags to words because it is dependent on other words in the sentence.  See this by printing out `w.pos_` for each word.  Lemmas are dependent on the POS tag so you'll see different results depending on if Spacy thinks it's a Noun or Verb, etc..

Comment: Stemming and lemmatization are not the same thing. Stemming basically shortens words, and the target is derivationally related forms. Lemmatization is the grammatical base of a word. For nouns, the lemma is singular, while for verbs, it's the infinitive form. Thus the lemma of "meeting" is "meeting" for a noun and "meet" for a verb. spaCy does not support stemming, though maybe someone has a plugin for it.

Comment: (This is on top of @bivouac0's correct comment about how you're not using it correct and POS tags are one cause of this issue.)

Comment: @bivouac0 I was applying Spacy Lemmatization after lowercasing the sentence and removing the stop words, hence the words could come in random order sometimes however in my above example it is randomly used words

So, if I need to use Spacy Lemmatization in more efficient way, I need to first apply lowercasing, then Lemmatization and then remove stop words?

Comment: Call `nlp()` on the full, unmodified sentence (ie.. don't lower-case or otherwise alter the sentence).  After `nlp()` has been called, you are free to collect words and lower-case them, remove stop words or collect the lemmas in whatever order you want.  Note that calling `w.lemma_` is only accessing the lemma tag that Spacy has already assigned, it's not a function call.